# A peerDependency is overriding a NX Library

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm using a monorepo with nx, with the following structure:

```
apps
  | - my-app
libs
  | - common
  | - my-client
```

The libs are being published on npm after the deployment under the names of `@my-org/my-client` and `@my-org/common`, while I'm defining the following path alias (on `tsconfig.conf`) to use them directly on `my-app` code:

```
"paths": {
      "@my-org/my-client": ["libs/my-client/src/index.ts"],
      "@my-org/common": ["libs/common/src/index.ts"]
}
```

The issue is that `my-app` is using an external package `another-external-package` that depends on `@my-org/common` (it's importing with its published version).

When I import `@my-org/common` on `my-app`, it seems that it's picking up the peer dependency `@my-org/common` (from `another-external-package`) and not from the alias that is defined on `tsconfig.conf`.
This happens only when we build for production but not in the dev environment.

Any idea on how to tell nx/tsc to pick the library instead of the published package?

Comment: This seems like a package manager(npm/yarn) or webpack issue. The aliases in tsconfig.paths are only for your IDE, the resolve happens at build time via ts-loader package in case you're using webpack which is default nx configuration for apps. I'm not familiar with webpack enough, but I'd search for a way to give it a hint to take the right package at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **package overrides**.

Try to add this in your package.json file:
(not sure if I've put it correctly for your situation)

```
  "overrides": {
    "@my-org/my-client": {
      "@my-org/common": "$@my-org/common"
    }
  }
```

It's explained here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

> If you need to make specific changes to dependencies of your
> dependencies, for example replacing the version of a dependency with a
> known security issue, replacing an existing dependency with a fork, or
> making sure that the same version of a package is used everywhere,
> then you may add an override.
>
> Overrides provide a way to replace a package in your dependency tree
> with another version, or another package entirely. These changes can
> be scoped as specific or as vague as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by adding directly the dependencies that are marked on the `tsconfig.conf` into the `package.json`, like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@my-org/common": "file:./libs/common"
}
```

This made `my-app` uses the local version of `@my-org/common` instead of using the peer dependency that was resolved via `@my-org/my-client`.

As @EcksDy mentioned:

> The aliases in tsconfig.paths are only for your IDE. The resolve happens at build time via ts-loader package in case you're using webpack which is default nx configuration for apps.

@johey: This is not about overriding the package that is called in the dependencies, but asking the app to use to the local version, and not the published one :)